# profile edit is not working when I change my component in profile detail

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

1.After I came to profile page that show my profile details my console log shows POST http://localhost:3000/profileEdit 500 (Internal Server error)

2.I change my activity drinks about topics and then refresh page it shows nothing like it didn't save at all except image

I debug by myself then tried to find solution in reddit, quora, stackoverflow 5 day but can't find it So please  could you help me a bit

this is frontend

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL, getStorage
} from "firebase/storage";
import { profileInit } from "../redux/action";
import "./profileEdit.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
const Avatar = styled.div`
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
cursor: pointer;
`;

function ProfileEdit(props) {
  const [cookies, removeCookies] = useCookies([
    "userName",
    "userNickname",
  ]);
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState("");
  const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState("");
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState("");
  const [about, setAbout] = useState("");
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("./images/UploadPic.svg");
  const [save, setSave] = useState("");
  const id = cookies.userName;
  const { profileInit, user } = props;
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
 
  function patchData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .patch("/users/profile", {
        activity,
        drinks,
        topics,
        about,
        id,
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        if (data.success) {
          setSave("Changes were saved");
        } else {
          setSave(data.err);
        }
      });
    const storage = getStorage();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${cookies.userName || "./images/infoUser.svg"}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", undefined, undefined, () => {
      getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
        setUrl(url);
      });
    });
    if (setUrl !== null || setUrl == null) {
      axios
        .patch("/users/profile", {
          activity,
          drinks,
          topics,
          about,
          id,
          avatar: url,
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          if (data.success) {
            setSave("Saved");
          } else {
            setSave(data.err);
          }
        });
    }
  }

  function handleChangeAbout(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setAbout(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleChangeDrinks(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setDrinks(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleChangeTopics(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTopics(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleChangeActivity(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setActivity(event.target.value);
  }
  function LogOut() {
    user.id = null;
    removeCookies("userName");
    removeCookies("userNickname");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `images/${cookies.userName}`))
      .then((url) => {
        setUrl(url);
      });
    axios
    .post('/users/profileEdit', {
      id,
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      setActivity(data.profileId.activity);
      setDrinks(data.profileId.drinks);
      setAbout(data.profileId.about);
      setTopics(data.profileId.topics);
      profileInit(data.profileId);
    });
  }, [profileInit, id]);

  function photoDownload(e) {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${cookies.userName}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        () => {
          setUrl("./loading.gif");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(storageRef)
            .then((url) => {
              setUrl(url);
            });
        },
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
     
      <div className="profile-container">
        <div style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
          <label htmlFor="file-input">
          <Avatar style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }} />
          </label>
          <input id="file-input" type="file" onChange={photoDownload} />
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={patchData} className="edit">
          <span
            style={{ textShadow: "none", marginBottom: "8px", color: "#fff" }}
          >
            Activity:
          </span>
          <label>
            <input
              value={activity}
              onChange={handleChangeActivity}
              type="text"
              name="activity"
              className="profileInput"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <span
            style={{ textShadow: "none", marginBottom: "8px", color: "#fff" }}
          >
            Topics:
          </span>
          <label>
            <input
              value={topics}
              onChange={handleChangeTopics}
              type="text"
              name="topics"
              className="profileInput"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <span
            style={{ textShadow: "none", marginBottom: "8px", color: "#fff" }}
          >
            About:
          </span>
          <label>
            <input
              value={about}
              onChange={handleChangeAbout}
              type="text"
              name="about"
              className="profileInput"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <span
            style={{ textShadow: "none", marginBottom: "8px", color: "#fff" }}
          >
            Drinks:
          </span>
          <label>
            <input
              value={drinks}
              onChange={handleChangeDrinks}
              type="text"
              name="drinks"
              className="profileInput"
              required
            />
          </label>
          <button
            style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}
            className="chatButton"
          >
            {" "}
            Save changes
            {" "}
          </button>
          <div style={{ marginTop: "15px", color: "#fff" }}>
            {" "}
            {save}
          </div>
        </form>

        <div className="quitEdit" style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
          <Link to="/listUsers" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
           <img src="./images/back.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="BackToListPage" title="BackToListPage" />
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="exit" style={{ margin: "0 auto" }}>
          <Link to="/login" onClick={LogOut} style={{ position: "relative" }}>
            <img src="./images/exit.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="Logout" title="Logout" />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profileId: state.user.profileId,
  user: state.user,
  err: state.error,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  profileInit: (profileId) => dispatch(profileInit(profileId)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileEdit);
```

my backend code for /users/profile and /users/profileEdit

```
router.patch('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  const {
    activity,
    topics,
    about,
    drinks,
    avatar,
    id,
  } = req.body;
  const response = await Profile.updateOne({ person: id }, {
    activity, topics, about, drinks, avatar
  });
  if (response) {
    res.send({ success: true });
  } else {
    res.send({ success: false, err: 'Try again' });
  }
});

router.post('/profileEdit', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  const response = await Profile.findOne({ person: id });
  if (response) {
    res.send({ profileId: response });
  } else {
    res.status(500).send({ err: 'Something went wrong' });
  }
});
```

Edit post here ->  modelProfile.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  person: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Person',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  DoB: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  activity: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  about: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
  },
  topics: String,
  drinks: String,
  avatar: String,
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
},
{
  versionKey: false,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema);
```

here is process page

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { LogIn } from "../redux/action";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ImageUpload from "./PhotoUpload";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { FromProcess, FromProcessContainer, ButtonCreate } from "./CreatingElements";

function CreatingAccount (props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [state,setState] = useState({
    currentStep: 1,
    name: "",
    DoB: "",
    activity: "",
    topics: "",
    drinks: "",
    about: ""
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,    // <-- copy previous state
      [name]: value, // <-- update property
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { user } = props;
    let { name, DoB, activity, topics, drinks, about } = state;
    await axios.post("/users/profile", {
      name,
      DoB,
      activity,
      topics,
      drinks,
      about,
      id: user.id
    });
    const profileId = {
      person: user.id,
      name,
      DoB,
      activity,
      about,
      topics,
      drinks
    };
   props.LogIn(user.id, user.nickname, profileId);
   navigate("/listUsers");
  };

  const _next = () => {
    let currentStep = state.currentStep;
    currentStep = currentStep >= 2 ? 3 : currentStep + 1;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,    // <-- copy previous state
      currentStep: currentStep// <-- update property
    }));
  };

  const _prev = () => {
    let currentStep = state.currentStep;
    currentStep = currentStep <= 1 ? 1 : currentStep - 1;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,    // <-- copy previous state
      currentStep: currentStep// <-- update property
    }));
  };
  
  function previousButton() {
    let currentStep = state.currentStep;
    if (currentStep !== 1) {
      return (
        <>
          <ButtonCreate
            style={{ color: "#3103ff" }}
            className="btn"
            type="button"
            onClick={_prev}
          >
            Previous
          </ButtonCreate>
          <br />
        </>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
  
  function nextButton() {
    let currentStep = state.currentStep;
    if (currentStep < 3) {
      return (
        <ButtonCreate
          className="btn"
          type="button"
          onClick={_next}
          data-cy="next-process"
          style={{
            marginBottom: "25px",
            color: "#FFF",
            backgroundColor: "#3103ff"
          }}
        >
          Next
        </ButtonCreate>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <>
     <FromProcessContainer>
      <FromProcess onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <p>Step {state.currentStep}</p>
        <br/>
        <Step1
          currentStep={state.currentStep}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          name={state.name}
          DoB={state.DoB}
          activity={state.activity}
        />
        <Step2
          currentStep={state.currentStep}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          topics={state.topics}
          drinks={state.drinks}
        />
        <Step3
          currentStep={state.currentStep}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          about={state.about}
        />
        {previousButton()}
        {nextButton()}
      </FromProcess>
      </FromProcessContainer>
    </>
  );
}

function Step1(props) {
  if (props.currentStep !== 1) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>
        <input
          value={props.name}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Your name"
          required
          data-cy="input-name-process"
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          value={props.DoB}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="date"
          name="DoB"
          placeholder="Date of Birth"
          max="2010-01-01"
          min="1930-12-31"
          required
          data-cy="input-Dob-process"
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          value={props.activity}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="activity"
          required
          placeholder="Place of work or study (required)"
          data-cy="input-activity-process"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

function Step2(props) {
  if (props.currentStep !== 2) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>
        <input
          value={props.topics}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="topics"
          placeholder="Favorite topics: (Optional)" 
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.drinks}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          name="drinks"
          placeholder="Favorite drink: (Optional)"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

function Step3(props) {
  if (props.currentStep !== 3) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <ImageUpload/>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          <input
            value={props.about}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="about"
            placeholder="Caption (Optional)"
          />
        </label>
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="btn"
        data-cy="submit-process"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#3103ff",
          marginBottom: "25px",
          color: "#FFF"
        }}
      >
        Save it
      </button>
      
    </>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  LogIn: (id, nickname, profileId) => dispatch(LogIn(id, nickname, profileId))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreatingAccount);
```

backend for /process

```
router.post('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  const {
    name,
    DoB,
    activity,
    topics,
    about,
    drinks,
    avatar,
    id,
  } = req.body;
  const user = await Person.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
  if (!user.profileId) {
    const newProfile = await Profile.create({
      person: id,
      name,
      DoB,
      activity,
      topics,
      about,
      drinks,
      avatar,
    });
    await Person.updateOne(user, { $set: { profileId: newProfile._id } });
    return res.send({
      success: true,
    });
  }
  await Person.updateOne({ _id: user.profileId }, {
    $set: {
      activity,
      topics,
      about,
      drinks,
      avatar,
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Before you jump to checking the backend first debug from the frontend. Are there any errors in the network tab (*i.e. is the POSY request made? Is there a response? etc...*)? Set a breakpoint near the top of the `handleSubmit` function and step through the code to see where anything is failing. Do try to update your post to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: I found sir it shows error at /users/profile which is my console shows at (see edited post)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong ?? so curious

Comment: I don't see any `activity` property accessed, but it seems the API endpoint is returning an error in the `data` property and the code is throwing an error when trying to access undefined nested properties when enqueueing state updates. Do you have the backend code handy? Or documentation for it if it's 3rd-party code?

Comment: So sorry it old error, New error is **place** instead of **activity**

Comment: I already edited it sir maybe my backend is not right

Comment: So to confirm, you *are* seeing the 500 status returned from the backend? What is `http://localhost:3000/profileEdit`, a page/component you are rendering by your app? Are your backend URLs prefixed with `"/users"`? Currently it's a bit unclear if the frontend is calling the backend correctly. The frontend usually runs on port 3000 and you'd normally run the backend on a different port, i.e. 5000, and you'd configure a proxy entry in your package.json to point there when running a local development build. Can you include more of how you are configuring and running these?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/profileEdit Is frontend code that shown above sir and /users is code in backend --> app.use('/users', usersRouter); which is linked to users.js in backend and my backend code in users.js are 2 above that I shown sir

Comment: But when I go to profile page (source code frontend above) and did nothing it just show error in console without doing anything

Comment: "proxy":"http://localhost:4000" I put this proxy path in package.json which is it works because I can login/register my webapp. This is code in backend for proxy --> const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4000');
app.set('port', port);

Comment: So *just navigating* to `"/profileEdit"` in the app throws an error? *How* are you navigating? Is that route path matched and the component rendered? What is that error? How are you running the React app?

Comment: Iam sorry again. code frontend above is localhost:3000/profile and this is code in app.js frontend to navigate to profile page -->  <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileEditPage/>} /> which after I go to  localhost:3000/profile it shows error in console without doing anything. Error shows **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)** and **Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError** sir.

Comment: ProfileEditPage is localhost:3000/profile

Comment: You should probably add a `.catch` block for the Promise chain to catch and handle rejected promises and thrown errors. Whatever this issue is seems to be related to that specific endpoint if the other endpoints are working as expected. Perhaps returning a status 500 isn't correct here. If you change it to `res.status(404).send({ err: 'Something went wrong' })` do you see the same issue in the frontend? This may help narrow down what exactly is causing an issue in the backend.

Comment: after I add `.catch(({error}) => {console.log(error); });` and change 500 to 404. It shows only **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: or Am I set **router.post('/profileEdit',...**  wrong

Comment: No, it seems like your endpoint is reachable. I wanted you to test changing the response to see if you got the different response back, and it seems you've confirmed that. From here it seems like `response` is falsey, so go investigate *that* part of the endpoint. Why isn't `Profile.findOne({ person: id })` returning the object you are expecting?

Comment: I import Profile `const Profile = require('../models/modelProfile');` and modelProfile.js is **see edit above at modelProfile.js** Maybe it has some mistake

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm asking what the value of `response` is from `const response = await Profile.findOne({ person: id });`?

Comment: undefined sir. and when I change some value in detail profile then refresh or switch page its not save at all except avatar

Comment: Sorry, what problem are you trying to solve right now? The backend `"profileEdit "` endpoint issue where it's not able to find a match? Or something in the frontend? I don't exactly understand what you mean by "when I change some value in detail profile then refresh or switch page its not save at all except avatar".

Comment: it's ok I'll summary this situation, 1. when I login/signin it would link to **http://localhost:3000/process** page which is for selecting name, date of birth, activity, topics, about, drinks and avatar. 2. when I finished selecting all of them then I have to click submit button for going to **http://localhost:3000/listUsers** page BUT nothing happen no error and I **stuck at /process** 3. I decided to go to **http://localhost:3000/listUsers** by typing url by myself then at **http://localhost:3000/listUsers** it has navbar for going through profile page (**http://localhost:3000/profile**) -->

Comment: 4. after I go to profile page **(localhost:3000/profile)** I show error undefined which I think its because I skip /process page that why it's error BUT even though  I change my activity, topics, about, drinks its not save at all except avatar.

Comment: 5.my mongodb is not save activity, topics, about, drinks at all in my account mongodb. but avatar is save in firebase storage which it works

Comment: first Frontend code that I shown you above is **localhost:3000/profile** .Now I show code in **localhost:3000/process** page in edit post including backend of /process page

Answer (score 0):

In your axios post, add a .then and a .catch, console.log() the result of the post whether its a success or a failure, also, not sure if u have the `favourite` variable defined globally but that might also be a source of the error

Comment: Now I change it to the same like my edited post but its the same sir

Comment: but when I change url to http://localhost:3000/listUsers (this path gonna show after clicking submit as I got problem above) which it saves only picture but name, place, age, favorite, caption are not saving in my detail profile at all

Comment: it seems like u need help with your overall code, private message with more details and ill try to help, or include all the details in your post with information about your listUsers logic

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

In the case of backend errors the API is returning a valid response that is missing a `profileId` property.

```
router.post('/profileEdit', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  const response = await Profile.findOne({ person: id });
  if (response) {
    res.send({ success: true, profileId: response });
  } else {
    res.send({ success: false, err: 'Something went wrong' }); // <-- here, no profileId
  }
});
```

This doesn't cause `axios` to return a Promise rejection and the frontend code assumes the response object has certain properties.

The error object returned is `{ success: false, err: 'Something went wrong' }` but the code is attempting to access into an undefined `profileId` property.

```
axios
  .post("/users/profileEdit", { id })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    setPlace(data.profileId.place); // <-- here, data.profileId undefined
    setAge(data.profileId.age);
    setFavorite(data.profileId.favorite);
    setCaption(data.profileId.cation);
    profileInit(data.profileId);
  });
```

`data.profileId` is undefined, and alone isn't an issue, it's later when trying to access the `place` property of an undefined object that an error is thrown.

## Solution

You can keep the backend code and do a check in the frontend for a successful POST request.

```
axios
  .post("/users/profileEdit", { id })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    if (data.success) {
      // POST success
      setPlace(data.profileId.place);
      setAge(data.profileId.age);
      setFavorite(data.profileId.favorite);
      setCaption(data.profileId.cation);
      profileInit(data.profileId);
    } else {
      // POST failure, check error
      // access data.err
    }
  });
```

It would be better to return a non-200 status code so axios can throw/handle a rejected Promise. You can read more about [HTTP status codes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Below I'm returning a super general Status 500 error, but you will want to be a specific as you need to be, i.e. a 404 if the specific person object isn't found.

Example:

```
router.post('/profileEdit', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  const response = await Profile.findOne({ person: id });
  if (response) {
    res.send({ profileId: response });
  } else {
    res.status(500).send({ err: 'Something went wrong' });
  }
});
```

...

```
axios
  .post("/users/profileEdit", { id })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // 200 responses
    const {
      profileId,
      profileId: { age, cation, favorite, place },
    } = data;
    setPlace(place);
    setAge(age);
    setFavorite(favorite);
    setCaption(cation);
    profileInit(profileId);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // non-200 responses
  });
```

Comment: So much appreciated sincerely but it error. TBH I think I miss something that I overlooked maybe I gonna give my source code to you personally thank again for helping me sir

Comment: @aozroveymo I referenced the node/express docs for the code/syntax, but granted, I had only your code as a starting reference point and didn't build a prototype to test. This should get you close to what you need if it isn't all the way there already.

Comment: appreciated sir I already sent it to you through gmail

Comment: @aozroveymo Oh, sorry, please don't send correspondence to individual users. The relevant code you are having an issue with should be included with the post so future readers will have the complete context.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I'll post it later sir

Comment: Sir my last edit that I edit my post entirely. I show every thing in frontend and backend for real. So sad that I can't find solution by myself but **So much appreciated** again for last help sir